# Como hacer un boton de "ME GUSTA" pero "Restringido"

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una web y tengo un contador de votos; Simplemente es un campo en una tabla que se llama **|Votos|**

Este campo admite valores INT. Sucede que cada vez que un usuario que llega a la web presiona un botón de **"VOTAR"** pues se suma un "VOTO" mas al contador del campo **|Votos|** (Todo bien). (Todo esto lo hago con sentencias SQL, tu sabes un "**INSERT INTO**" etc... y uso **PHP**)

Sin embargo me estoy dando cuenta de que un usuario podría presionar varias veces el mismo boton de **"VOTAR"**  y necesito restringirlo a 1 sola vez por usuario logueado a la web (Como el típico botón de me gusta de las redes sociales que si pulsas de nuevo el voto anterior se "ANULA")

Mi pregunta (Aunque un tanto laxa) es; ¿Cómo se hace esto? Es decir se que hay una comparativa en **IF** entre **ALGO** y el **BOTON PRESIONADO**  pero **ese algo ¿Qué es?** la **"IP"** la variable **$_SESSION**¿?

Si alguien puede orientarme un poco se lo agradeceré.

Comment: *...a 1 sola vez por usuario logueado...* Estás usando sesiones, o sea, el principal problema ya lo tienes resuelto. Problema sería si tuvieses que validar por IP (que también cambia), cookies u otros datos de votación anónima. Al cargar la vista, verifica si el usuario activo tiene un voto con ese ID. Si es así coloca el botón de "votado", de lo contrario, que "puede votar". Y en la BD vas cambiando el estatus (0 o 1) del voto (o lo borras y reinsertas) por cada vez que presione el botón.

Comment: ¿Pero como verifico si el usuario activo tiene un voto? ¿Entonces tengo que darle a cada usuario un campo |Voto| y hacer una relacion de 1 a muchos? (Si comprendo lo que sugieres, solo que como que no desgloso la naturaleza del problema) por eso preguntaba;

¿Es una relación de uno a muchos o algo así? (No logro como que verlo claro

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de colocar un poco más de información de la escrutura de tus tablas y el código dónde estás realizando tal acción. Pero, aquí te van unos pasos a considerar.

**Paso 1:**
Primero, deberías de revisar si tu tabla donde guardas el conteo de votos, también estás guardando el ID del usuario. De esa manera será mucho más fácil.

**Paso 2:**
Verifica también en tu tabla donde llevas el conteo, si estás guardando alguna especie de ID o algún identificador de lo que están votando. Por ejemplo, si pensamos en facebook, el ID de cada post que se publica, debería estar acompañado de un ID del usuario que le dio Me Gusta. De esa manera, al momento de hacer la consulta podrás saber si ya votó.

**Paso 3:**
Una consulta que podrías realizar si ya tienes los dos campos que te mencioné arriba sería lo siguiente en SQL:

```
SELECT count(ID) FROM TablaContador WHERE user_id = IdDeUsuario AND post_id = IdDelPostAVotar;
```

Nota que estoy utilizando el count para saber si hay alguna votación hecha por el usuario, en este caso devolverá 1 si ya votó y 0 sino lo ha hecho.

**Paso 4:**
Esto lo tendrías que hacer en PHP cuando recojas el valor que te retornaron:

```
if (ValorDeConsulta == 1) {
    echo "Usuario ya votó";
} else {
    "Aquí meterías el código donde haces el registro del voto"
}
```

Esta sería una idea que podrías implementar. Aunque como te menciono hace falta que pongas los fragmentos de código para darte una idea más precisa de lo que necesitas hacer. Saludos!!!